# CSS Position fixed not fixing header to top

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, z-index

I am trying to fix the position of my header and cause a CSS transition on certain amount of scroll like [this link](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/AnimatedHeader/)

I appended the position fixed for the header, in the header div, with the `top:0` which apparently is a common mistake, unfortunately, the header keeps scrolling away. I checked with google chrome dev tools and noticed that the header's ghost remains, making it seem like a z-index issue but I am not so sure that's the problem. I did try fiddling around with the z-index but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Since the links will definitely die when the site is updated. Here is the issue, my parent div is styled (via Some external js files) as:

```
#parentDiv {
position: relative;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; //problem styling
-webkit-perspective: 500;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: If backface-visibility: hidden; is removed from parent div style - header works fine. What lib adds this styling?

Comment: You are a savior sir! I think it might be one of the JS files

Comment: Seems like the handiwork of skel-panels.min.js file since this happens to reference the div.

Comment: @sleepwalker, maybe time to post that comment as a answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open skel-panels JS file, find `.css("backface-visibility","hidden")` there and remove it.